# LinearLayout not resizing ImageViews correctly

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-imageview

As part of the on-boarding for my app, I have a series of translucent overlays that highlight the UI.  Each one is a LinearLayout, initially invisible (actually "gone"), that I make visible in turn.  I am having a very tough time getting one of these to display correctly on both tablets and phones, in both portrait and landscape.  I can tune it to work on the phone, but then it doesn't display well on tablet-portrait.

The images here are set up to work well on 10" tablets in portrait, and they work for 7" tablets and phones in portrait, but not in landscape.  In the images below, I would like the arrows (two ImageViews) to resize as needed to make room for the text.  However, the Layout seems to give priority to the ImageViews no matter what I do.

(Note that I do realize I could make this work, in a way, with a RelativeLayout, however, I cannot get the translucent backgrounds to work, filling the screen, using a RelativeLayout, as far as I know.)

My question in brief:  **Is there a way to make LinearLayout prioritize the TextViews, giving them enough space, and resizing the ImageViews to fit the rest?**

Here is a good layout (10" tablet, portrait, shown at reduced scale):
[image: 10" tablet, portrait]

Here is a bad one with some of the text cut off (10" tablet, landscape, reduced scale):
[image: 10" tablet, landscape]

Here is another bad one (phone):
[image: phone, portrait]

I don't have a screenshot of the other tuning, but it displayed big arrows and no central "Tap to Continue" button.

Here is my current XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_holder"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/intro3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:onClick="introClicked"
        android:clickable="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/intro3_top"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="top|center_horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewIntro3_1"
                fontPath="fonts/AsCuteAs...Heavy.ttf"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Swipe up to mark a spark completed."
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:background="#C5000000"
                android:textColor="#fff6c3"
                android:textSize="30sp"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                android:adjustViewBounds="false"
                android:background="@drawable/grad_bottom"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/arrow_up"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="#85000000"
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/button_intro3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:alpha="0"
                android:background="@drawable/roundrect"
                android:onClick="introClicked"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Tap to Continue"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:textColor="#FFFFF6C3"
                android:textSize="24sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/intro3_bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                android:adjustViewBounds="false"
                android:background="@drawable/grad_top"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/arrow_down"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewIntro3_2"
                fontPath="fonts/AsCuteAs...Heavy.ttf"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Swipe down to reject.\n "
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                android:background="#C5000000"
                android:textColor="#fff6c3"
                android:textSize="30sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Where you have given `weight` in the layouts there make the height as `0dp`.

Comment: You can also set a total `weightSum` on the LinearLayout, then you have to mess with the `weight` values to do percentages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're several possible way of doing it. I've updated your layout a bit, so now it should meet your expectations:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_holder"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/intro3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:onClick="introClicked"
        android:clickable="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewIntro3_1"
            fontPath="fonts/AsCuteAs...Heavy.ttf"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Swipe up to mark a spark completed."
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:background="#C5000000"
            android:textColor="#fff6c3"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/button_intro3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textViewIntro3_1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:background="@drawable/grad_bottom"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_up"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/button_intro3"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:alpha="0"
            android:background="@drawable/roundrect"
            android:onClick="introClicked"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Tap to Continue"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:textColor="#FFFFF6C3"
            android:textSize="24sp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:background="@drawable/grad_top"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button_intro3"
            android:layout_above="@+id/textViewIntro3_2"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_down"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewIntro3_2"
            fontPath="fonts/AsCuteAs...Heavy.ttf"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Swipe down to reject.\n "
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            android:background="#C5000000"
            android:textColor="#fff6c3"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

What I did here is to rewrite the layout with `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout`s. It suits better here, in my humble opinion.

I hope, it helps.

Comment: That solution is very close to working, @konstantin-loginov!  The central button has no background, but by enclosing it in a simple FrameLayout, it works well.  I had tried RelativeLayouts before, but somehow the background had never worked.  Thanks for the help!